# Is NSTimer the most energy efficient timer?

Tags: iphone, ipad, swift2, xcode7, nstimer

**(Swift on Xcode 7.3)**
I'm currently working on two independent iPhone apps, both of which use events fired by a repeating NSTimer.

Application A displays an analogue clock with a smooth second hand movement.  The timer fires every second and advances all three clock hands appropriately.

Application B displays a weather forecast which is updated every fifteen minutes, after first checking the iPhone's current location.

The question is, is using NSTimer for each of these apps an efficient use of the iphone's resources?  If not, what alternatives are available for firing regular events.

(The long term plan is to combine both of these iPhone applications - once they have been refined - into a larger iPad application.)

Comment: The clock isn't inferring the time from the timer but setting the clock to the correct time every second.  Animation makes the process look smooth,  I realise that I could set the timer to longer intervals but haven't gotten around to trying it out yet.

Comment: What are the other alternatives? I suspect that you've already black-listed the `NSThread` + `sleep` solution.

Comment: I don't see many better ways of doing it.  A 1-second timer is not at all resource intensive.